# Hyperledger Fabric 2.0, Can't Access Fabtokens of Users Using Node.js SDK

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I'm trying to issue some Fabtokens to users and then use them in various scenarios such as transferring, redeeming, etc. I follow the Node SDK documentation here: https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/master/tutorial-fabtoken.html

This is how they do the Fabtoken operations:

```
// create a TokenClient instance from client
const tokenclient = client.newTokenClient(mychannel);

// create a transaction ID for "issuer"
const txId = client.newTransactionID();

// create two parameters for issue, one for user1 and one for user2
const param1 = {
    owner: user1.getIdentity().serialize(),
    type: 'USD',
    quantity: '500',
};
const param2 = {
    owner: user2.getIdentity().serialize(),
    type: 'EURO',
    quantity: '300',
};

// create the token request for issue
const issueRequest = {
    params: [param1, param2],
    txId: txId,
};

// issuer calls issue method to issue tokens to user1 and user2
const result = await tokenClient.issue(issueRequest);
```

And then use a different tokenClient to list the tokens of user 1:

```
const user1Tokenclient = client1.newTokenClient(mychannel);

// user1 lists tokens
const mytokens = await user1TokenClient.list();

// iterate the tokens to get token id, type, and quantity for each token
for (const token of tokens) {
    // get token.id, token.type, and token.quantity
    // token.id will be used for transfer and redeem
}
```

It's mentioned on the Node SDK's Client class page here: https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/master/Client.html that switching userContexts with the same client instance is an anti-pattern and not recommended since client instances are stateful.

As they suggest, I create my client instances with different user contexts. This is how I create my clients, set their user context and create my tokenClient instances:

```
const adminClient = new Fabric_Client();
const admin = await adminClient.createUser(user_opts);
adminClient.setUserContext(admin, true);
let adminConfig = {
    admin: admin,
    adminClient: adminClient,
    adminTokenClient: adminClient.newTokenClient(channel)
}

const server = await serverClient.createUser(server_opts); 
serverClient.setUserContext(server, true);
let serverConfig = {
    server: server,
    serverClient: serverClient,
    serverTokenClient: serverClient.newTokenClient(channel)
}
```

Later on, I'm using these `config` objects to issue some tokens to different users. How I issue tokens to my server account from my issuer (admin) account:

```
const txId = adminConfig.adminClient.newTransactionID();
let issueQuery = {
    tokenClient: adminConfig.adminTokenClient,
    txId: txId,
    channel: channel,
    params: []
}

for(let i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
    let param = {
        owner: serverConfig.server.getIdentity().serialize(),
        type: 'test',
        quantity: '1'
    }
    issueQuery.params.push(param);
}
let issueTx = await waitForIssue(issueQuery);
```

This successfully issue three tokens to the server as expected. The problem is that when I try to access to the tokens of my server like the example they provide using a similar code:

```
let server_tokens = await serverConfig.serverTokenClient.list();
for (let server_token of server_tokens) {
    console.log(server_token.id);
}
```

Result is just empty and I don't get any error messages. However, when I check the transaction using `queryTransaction(txId)` for the  token issue transaction I generate, I can see that owner of the issued tokens in that transaction is the server and that's how I can be sure that I can successfully issue the tokens to the server. Is there any other way to check the tokens of my server? Or shouldn't I use a different client and user context per each user as they suggest? Because, previously I was able to see the tokens of the server when I used a single client and single user context to issue and list tokens. But this approach caused me problems when I was trying to transfer my tokens asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know FabTokens are removed from the Master branch of Fabric 2.0 now as described in these links:

https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/c/fabric/+/32979

https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/fabtoken/34150195?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,0,34150195

I would expect the tutorial and the information in the Fabric docs to be removed in due course.

Comment: I saw that but I downloaded Fabric 2.0 a while ago so I have the TokenClient in my current Node SDK. It works fine but there are issues that I got stuck with and doesn't work as explained in their Fabtoken examples.